# How to define a Django template method to avoid duplicating of code in html?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, duplicates

I have two different UI pages. In both of the pages, 2 out of 5 html elements are common and rest 3 are not. How to avoid duplicating the code?

Current implementation:

```
{% if page 1 %}
      <h3> Page 1 </h3>
      <div> Element1 </div>
      <div> Element2 </div>
      <div> Element3 </div>
      <div> Element4 </div>
      <div> Element5 </div>
{% elif page 2 %}
      <h3> Page 2 </h3>
      <div> Element1 </div>
      <div> Element2 </div>
      <div> Element6 </div>
      <div> Element7 </div>
      <div> Element8 </div>
```

How to avoid writing  Element1            Element2  twice ?

Comment: I find it rather strange that you here perform paging yourself. Django has a way to perform paging itself. Furthermore I do not really get why certain elements occur on *both* pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the common elements into a separate template file, say `firstelements.html`, and then use

```
{% include "firstelements.html" %}
```

in the template.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a single template HTML file with all the elements you want to repeat multiple times in your code and later in your code use `{% include %}` tag to include that HTML.